# Empty object being sent to excel file c#

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to write a c# program to make a Bank system with users creating bank accounts. And I want to be able to save these accounts given through the console to an excel file so it can retrieve them later if needed.

I followed a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3S3aI8nMeE&t=651s) on how to do that and made minor adjustments to the code but when I try to run the program with some test accounts it writes them as blank accounts with no data and I can't see why it would do this.

```
public class Account
    {
        protected static int count = 1;
        protected int accountNum;
        protected string fName;
        protected string lName;
        protected int idNumber;
        protected string address;
        protected DateOnly birthday = new();
        protected bool flag;

        Savings.SpendingRef = Spendings(accountNum);

        public Account(string fn, string ln, int idnum, string add, DateOnly bd)
        {
            //System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
            this.accountNum = count++;
            fName = fn;
            lName = ln;
            idNumber = idnum;
            address = add;
            birthday = bd;
            flag = false;
        }

        public int AccountNum{get;}
        public string FName{get; set;}
        public string LName{get; set;}
        public int IdNumber{get; set;}
        public string Address{get; set;}
        public DateOnly Birthday{get;}
        public bool Flag{get; set;}

        public string GetAccount(){
            string s = "--------------------------------\n";

            s += "Account Number :" + accountNum + "\nAccount belonging to :" + fName + " " + LName + "\nID Number :" + IdNumber + "\nAddress :" + address + "\nBirthday : " + birthday + "\nAccount blocked? :" + flag;

            s += "\n--------------------------------\n";
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            return s;
        }
    }
```

Here is how the account class is implemented

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
    var file = new FileInfo(@"..\..\..\SavedAccounts.XLSX");

    //Other code not important

    var Accounts = GetSetupData();

    await SaveExcelFile(Accounts, file);
}

private static List<Account> GetSetupData()
{
    List<Account> output = new()
    {
        new Account("Jerome", "Dupret", 42069, "68 rue des ecoles", new DateOnly(1999, 08, 10)),
        new Account("Deborah", "Pierre", 69420, "68 rue des ecoles", new DateOnly(2000, 02, 18)),
    };

    return output;
}
```

Here are the test accounts I want to be inserted.

```
private static async Task SaveExcelFile(List<Account> accounts, FileInfo file)
{

    DeleteIfExists(file);

    using var package = new ExcelPackage(file);//basically a Dispose method to get rid of any useless data

    var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("AccountData");

    var range = ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(accounts, true);
    range.AutoFitColumns();

    await package.SaveAsync();
}
```

And this is where the call and the write function itself happen.
I used console Writes at every step to check if the accounts lose info at any time but they never do, I'm confused as to why it isn't sent properly.

[image: This is what I end up getting.]

Comment: Please show your implementation of the `Account` class. I suppose the problem is there

Comment: Sorry here it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you never set your public properties such as `Fname`, either you need to set them in the constructor or make the getter get the protected field.

for example

```
protected string fName;

public string FName
    {
        get
        {
            return fName;
        }
        set
        {
            fName = value;
        }
    }
```

This needs to be done on all the public fields so they all get the field that gets set in the constructor.

The set is not required but if you dont use it `FName` and `fName` can become diffrent values since `fName` is only set in the constructor.

Comment: I believe I did initialise the constructor.
I wrote:
public string FName{get; set;}
Unless this isn't the appropriate way to write it in this case

Comment: @Jeromeo Yes you did, the problem is the Excel API can only access public properties so it tries to get FName which never gets set so results null. The getter currently only gets FName which never gets set